# Find and replace within a multidimensional hash - Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

If you take a hash:

```
{
   :element => {
      :to_find => 'found me'
   },
   :element_2 => {
      :inner_element => {
         :n_elements => {
            :to_find => 'found me'
         }
       :do_not_touch => 'still here'
      }
   }
}
```

How could I find and replace the :to_find with 'changed'?

I have attempted

```
(hash).update(hash){|k,v| (([:to_find].include? k) ? 'changed' : v}
```

however this is only one deep.

I could make a recursive function such has as:

```
def change_keys(hash, keys, new_value)
   (hash).update(hash) do |k,v| 
       if (keys.include? k) 
         new_value
       else
          if v.class == Hash 
            find_key(v)
          else
            v
          end
       end
    end
end
```

I have tested that running this, works:

```
change_keys(my_hash, [:to_find], 'changed')
```

However, is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A recursive method is the way to go, but you can make it cleaner...

```
def change_keys(hash, keys, new_value)
    keys.each { |k|  hash[k] = new_value if hash.has_key?(k) }
    hash.values.each { |v| change_keys(v, keys, new_value)  if v.class == Hash }
end
```

Comment: I can't edit the code because the change is less than 6 characters, but you need a `.` before the `each` in line 3

Comment: Thanks, well-spotted, @BrunoAntunes, change now made.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this

```
eval({
  :x => 'y',
  :q => 
  {
    :x => 'y',
    :s => 
      {
        :x => 'y'
      }
  }
}.to_s.gsub(/:x=>"."/, ':x=> "new_value"')
)
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but if you look at his "I have attempted..." you'll see he wants to change the value, not the key.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn thank you for comment, i corrected my answer